# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have errors when want to install npm install node-saas

> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.2
>
> └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.4.2
>
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^0.14.1, required by
>   react-select@0.9.1
>
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^0.14.1, required by
>   react-select@0.9.1
>
> npm ERR! code 1

Please help, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to install `react` and `react-dom`, first run this command it will install `react` and `react-dom` properly with all dependencies, after that run other commands.

```
npm install react react-dom --save
```

By using `--save` it will make a entry in `package.json` file, after using above command check your `package.json` file, these entries will be there:

```
"react": "^XX.X.X",
"react-dom": "^XX.X.X",
```